# com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper: less restrictive mode?

Tags: csv, jackson-dataformat-csv

CSV ("comma separated values") files, like many data sources, can have aberrations:

- More or fewer fields than there are columns.
- Field values that might present challenges (Eg, containing the field-separator).

Is there some way to configure the jackson `CsvMapper` so that is operates more liberally:  ie, is less restrictive with regard to parsing the data records in CSV files?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into the configuration options for `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper`.  The setup below helped me deal with trailing, unmatched columns (in my case, one or more commas with no field content between them):

```
CsvMapper csvMapper = (new CsvMapper()).configure(Feature.IGNORE_TRAILING_UNMAPPABLE, true);
```